# Check existence of file and return if exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using Node.js and I would like to check if a file exists and return the result to a property of a object. I'm trying like this:

```
var file_exists = function(file) {
 return fs.stat(file, function(error, stat) {
    if (error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
};

result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
 result.push({
   exists: file_exists(file[i])
 });
}
```

But is returning undefined. This is because of asynchronous?

How could i fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a concept's mistake, When you execute fs.stat, the callback runs inner his own scope. The return true/false, does not return in the file_exists function scope.

You can use [fs.statSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path)

```
var file_exists = function(file) {
 try {
    fs.statSync(file);
 } catch (e) {
    return false;
 }

 return true;

};
```